# Print and download excel are not working in swimlane/ngx-datatable

Tags: css, angular, angular8, ngx-datatable

Tried to set print and download options for ngx-datatable but it is not working. Print table css also not working. I do not know how to resolve this issue. If anyone know please help to find the solutions.

demo.component.ts:

```
  printData(){

   var printContents = document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML; 
   var WindowObject = window.open('', "PrintWindow", "width=700,height=850,top=200,left=200,toolbars=no,scrollbars=no,status=no,resizable=no");
    WindowObject.document.writeln(printContents);
    WindowObject.document.close();
    WindowObject.focus();
    WindowObject.print();
    WindowObject.close(); 

  }

  downloadExl(elem){ 
 
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var html = table.outerHTML;
  var url = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + escape(html);  
  elem.setAttribute("href", url);
  elem.setAttribute("download", "export.xls");  
  return false;
  
  }
```

Demo:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-datatable-responsive-demo-v4bzat?file=app%2Fdemo-component.ts

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, I had to use another library and tools to solve this. By creating a service which i use through-out the app.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import jsPDF from "jspdf";
import html2canvas from "html2canvas";
   
@Injectable({
        providedIn: "root",
    })

export class PrintpdfService {
    constructor() {}

    exportAsPDF(div_id, doc_name = "tax") {
        let data = document.getElementById(div_id);
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        html2canvas(data).then((canvas) => {
            var wid = canvas.width;
            var hgt = canvas.height;
            var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            var hratio = hgt / wid;
            var doc = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");
            var width = doc.internal.pageSize.width;
            var height = width * hratio;
            doc.addImage(img, "JPEG", 20, 20, width, height);
            doc.save(doc_name + ".pdf"); // Generated PDF
        });
    }

    printPdf(div_id) {
        let data = document.getElementById(div_id);
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        html2canvas(data).then((canvas) => {
            var wid = canvas.width;
            var hgt = canvas.height;
            var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            var hratio = hgt / wid;
            // var doc = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");
            var doc = new jsPDF("p", "mm", [387, 210]);
            var width = doc.internal.pageSize.width;
            var height = width * hratio;
            doc.addImage(img, "JPEG", 20, 20, width, height);
            window.open(doc.output("bloburl"), "_blank");

            // doc.autoPrint({variant: 'non-conform'});
        });
    }
}
```

In my component.html

- I will then wrap my html with this props - id="pdfTable" #pdfTable

In my component.ts

- I will call the funtion by passing passing the id